# Is there a way to change the animation style of a modal view controller appearance?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-animation

I am trying to animate the appearance and disappearance of two view controllers' view.

I used the following two lines of code:

```
self.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];
```

to make the view controller's view animate in from the bottom of the screen, which works well.

My question is: can I change the style of this animation so that the view isn't always sliding in from the bottom of the screen?  How can I make it animate in from the top of the screen, for example?

Comment: `presentModalViewController` is deprecated since iOS 6.

Comment: Thanks for your interest on much old question.

Answer (score 15):

The `modalTransitionStyle` property on a view controller sets how that view controller will appear, not the animation that it will use to present a different controller. So you'd do something like:

```
viewcontroller.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical; 
[self presentModalViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];
```

(and I'm in the habit of having view controllers dictate their own modal transition style in an overridden initWithCoder:, but that's a style question I guess).

The list of available transition styles is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIModalTransitionStyle). So, to try the animation where one controller flips over like a playing card, as if the other were printed on the opposite side:

```
viewcontroller.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal; 
[self presentModalViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];
```